# How do i extend the Register method in django-rest-auth in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

Currently, when my user registers and there is an error, I get the following message back:

```
status 400
{"username":["This field is required."],"email":["A user is already registered with this e-mail address."],"__all__":["You must type the same password each time."]}
```

This is for my mobile application and I would like a consistent message when the error is returned (not field specific like 'username', 'email'). For example,

```
status 400
{"error_message":"username - This field is required. email - A user is already registered with this e-mail address. __all__ - You must type the same password each time."}
```

Is there anyway I can extend the registration/views/Register class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the `RegisterView.get_response_with_errors` method.

```
class MyRegisterView(RegisterView):
    def get_response_with_errors(self):
        errors = my_magic_func(self.form.errors)
        return Response(errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Where `my_magic_func` will do the trick of customizing error message based on the error dict. Then hook up the custom view into your urls:

```
url(r'^rest-auth/registration/$', MyRegisterView.as_view(), name='rest_register'),
```

remember to add it before any `rest-auth` related urls.